# Unable to locate package rocon-interactions

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
sudo apt-get install rocon-interactions
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rocon-interactions
```

How to resolve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223727/unable-to-locate-package-rocon-interactions/) by [carriewang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25515/carriewang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you need to specify the ROS version,  `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rocon-interactions` if it is indigo you have installed

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0